# Using "SQL_NO_CACHE" statement in HQL from Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I am using hibernate 4.x and want to set the "SQL_NO_CACHE" statement from MySQL inside a HQL query

```
@Query("FROM mytable t WHERE id=1");
```

currently produces

```
select * from mytable where id=1
```

but I want

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE * from mytable where id=1
```

but I cannot figure out how.

No problem using a native query, but all query are written in HQL and are much more complex than this example. So I am getting a `QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token` Exception, since this statement is not documented anyhow in the hibernate documentation.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html

Comment: Well it is obviosuly unrealistic for Hibernate to support every RDBMS specific satement so Native SQL will be the only option here.

Comment: sure, but I even didn't find a documented approach to extend the HqlParser to add this on my own

Comment: Further to previous maybe you can actually do this by means of a Custom Dialect. See here for an example: http://keyurj.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/creating-custom-dialect-in-hibernate.html

Answer (score 1):

It is possible create a view that has this clause SQL_NO_CACHE. Then when hibernate run your SQL query you can override the PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl.toPhysicalTableName and change to get the name your view instead your table. For example, the default name is 'mytable' and your view name is 'vw_mytable', then concatenate 'vw_' before name your table.

Put this implementation from PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl in your persistence file  in property "hibernate.physical_naming_strategy" and yours querys will use the clause SQL_NO_CACHE.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`StatementInspector`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/resource/jdbc/spi/StatementInspector.html) to alter generated SELECT statements. On how to use it see the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112308/how-i-can-configure-statementinspector-in-hibernate).