# How I can configure StatementInspector in Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jdbc, inspect

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html
 says that onPrepareStatement(String sql) is Deprecated.  Supply a StatementInspector instead, if you wish to inspect and alter SQL statements.

But I am not clear how I can configure StatementInspector in Hibernate at application level (i don't want to set it at each hibernate session level).

Answer (score 8):

The best way to register a `StatementInspector` is to use the [`hibernate.session_factory.statement_inspector`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-statementinspector/) configuration property.

This way, it does not matter whether you are bootstrapping Hibernate using JPA (e.g. Spring Data JPA) or native Hibernate (e.g. Spring with `HibernateTranscationManager` and `LocalSessionFactoryBean`).

So, you can to provide the `hibernate.session_factory.statement_inspector` via the `persistence.xml` JPA configuration file:

```
<property
    name="hibernate.session_factory.statement_inspector"
    value="com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.logging.inspector.SqlCommentStatementInspector"
/>
```

Or, you can also set the `hibernate.session_factory.statement_inspector` programmatically if you're using Spring:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan({
        "com.vladmihalcea.books.high.performance.java.persistence"
    });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
      = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
      "hibernate.session_factory.statement_inspector", 
      SqlCommentStatementInspector.class
    );
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
      "hibernate.dialect", 
      "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"
    );

    return hibernateProperties;
}
```

Notice that the `hibernate.session_factory.statement_inspector` setting can take either a `String` representing he fully-qualified class implementing the `StatementInspector` interface, a `Class<? extends StatementInspector>` or a `StatementInspector` object reference.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer` in Spring

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Bean
    public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer configureStatementInspector() {
        return (properties) -> properties.put(AvailableSettings.STATEMENT_INSPECTOR, (StatementInspector) sql -> {
            // figure out what to return
            return sql;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't do like that )

You need only two things:

1. Add property to persistence.xml:

property name="hibernate.session_factory.statement_inspector" value="full-qualified class name"

2. Write your listener class by implementing interface org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.spi.StatementInspector.

Profit!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this to work, you have to bootstrap Hibernate. To do this:

In your main class, find your EntityManagerFactory instance. It probably looks something like this:

```
public static final EntityManagerFactory EMPFAC = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpa")
```

Leave that line for now. Above it, add the following:

```
private static StandardServiceRegistryBuilder servReg = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
static {
    //Do this for every property in persistence.xml
    servReg.applySetting("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc://myurl://www.example.org");
}
```

Add a `servReg.applySetting()` for every property in `persistence.xml`. Then, add this below it:

```
private static MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(servReg.build());
static {
    // Do this for every pojo with JPA annotations
    sources.addAnnotatedClass(Pojo.class);
}
```

Add a `sources.addAnnotatedClass()` for every JPA-annotated pojo in your application. Almost done here. Now create a class that implements `StatementInspector` like so:

```
public class Inspector implements StatementInspector {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5545844969759630544L;

   @Override
   public String inspect(String select) {
       // modify string here
       return select;
   }
}
```

Finally, go back to your main application class, and, underneath the static block where you registered your pojos, add the following:

```
public static final SessionFactory EMPFAC = sources.buildMetadata().getSessionFactoryBuilder().applyStatementInspector(new Inspector()).build();
```

Now you can go back to `persistence.xml` and delete the property declarations there. If you haven't already, also delete your `public static final EntityManager` declaration (you've replaced it with the SessionFactory).

EDIT: You can actually delete `persistence.xml` and your application should still work fine.

All set!

Comment: this is not necessary, just set the property as shown in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Things haven't changed much - basically some things were renamed, so from the old "Interceptor" code-examples you find online, you just need to adapt these name-changes. If you manually build your SessionFactory (as I do), you can do it like this:

```
public class MyInspector implements StatementInspector {
   @Override
   public String inspect(String sql) {
       System.out.println(sql); // or whatever you want to do
       return sql;
   }
}
```

Then, while setting up your SessionFactory, you insert it very much the same way you inserted the Interceptor before

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "myusername");
// ...
config.addAnnotatedClass(SomeClass.class);
// ...
config.setStatementInspector(new MyInspector()); // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
SessionFactory mySessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
// do something with the session factory
```

see [setInterceptor in 6.1](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#setInterceptor(org.hibernate.Interceptor))
in comparison to [setStatementInspector in 6.2](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#setStatementInspector(org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.spi.StatementInspector))